# JS error while implementing suggest with Coveo

Tags: coveo

I'm implementing a field based suggestions with a coveosearchbox view. My searchbox is declared like this:

```razor
 <div class="CoveoSearchbox form-control"
         data-auto-focus="@Model.AutoFocus"
         data-enable-lowercase-operators="@Model.EnableLowercaseOperators"
         data-enable-partial-match="@Model.EnablePartialMatch"
         data-partial-match-keywords="@Model.PartialMatchKeywords"
         data-partial-match-threshold="@Model.PartialMatchThreshold"
         data-enable-question-marks="@Model.EnableQuestionMarks"
         data-enable-wildcards="@Model.EnableWildcards"
         data-enable-omnibox="true"
         data-omnibox-timeout="@Model.OmniboxTimeout"
         data-enable-field-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableFieldAddon"
         data-enable-simple-field-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableSimpleFieldAddon"
         data-enable-top-query-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableTopQueryAddon"
         data-enable-reveal-query-suggest-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableRevealQuerySuggestAddon"
         data-enable-query-extension-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableQueryExtensionAddon">
        <span class="CoveoFieldSuggestions" data-header-title="Results" data-field="@Model.ToCoveoFieldName("title")"></span>          
    </div>
```

But when I start typing on the coveo search box the suggest is not working. The error I get is:

> SearchEndpointWithDefaultCallOptions.ts:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined(…)

I'm using Coveo for Sitecore version 4.402 on a Sitecore 8.1 installation. Also on the diagnostics page I see all services as up and running. I'm assuming this is a misconfiguration but I'm not being able to pinpoint which one. any thoughts on what's wrong here?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using suggestions, you must also use the "Coveo Search Resources"  component. The "Coveo Search Box Resources" component is too minimal to support suggestions.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. thanks Jeff it works!